# Using JsonPatchDocument With PatchAsync In Blazor Client

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

In my Blazor Client project, I have the following code:

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch

    ...

    var doc = new JsonPatchDocument<Movie>()
         .Replace(o => o.Title, "New Title");

    await Http.PatchAsync("api/patch/" + MovieId, doc);
```

This won't compile with the following error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument'
>   to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

After some research, I've installed `Newtonsoft.Json` but I'm unsure how to configure the project to use it, or if indeed this is the correct solution for getting `JsonPatchDocument` working in a Blazor Project?

If `JsonPatchDocument` is not supported by Blazor, how can I implement a HTTP Patch request?

Comment: Did you try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.patchasync?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @enet Thanks for replying, yes I did but that document doesn't describe how a JsonPatchDocument object can be used as the HttpContent parameter, or if such an object is supported within a Blazor Client project.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a different but related issue. You are correct that you need to be using `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of `System.Text.Json` on the client application. Here is an extension method that will turn your `JsonPatchDocument` into an `HttpContent`.

```
 public static class HttpClientExtensions
 {
     public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync<T>(this HttpClient client,
     string requestUri,
     JsonPatchDocument<T> patchDocument)
     where T : class
 {
     var writer = new StringWriter();
     var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     serializer.Serialize(writer, patchDocument);
     var json = writer.ToString();

     var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
     return await client.PatchAsync(requestUri, content);
 }
```

I know it's late but I hope it's helpful.